# decorator in python invocation sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying write a decorator in python 3 which basically keeps a count on the number of times a function gets called.
Here is my code:

```
def call_counter(func):
  def helper(x):
      helper.calls += 1
      return func(x)

  helper.calls = 0

  return helper


@call_counter
def succ(x):
  return x + 1

for i in range(10):
  print(succ(i))   # <--- ??
```

I understand how decorator works but only confusion I have here is that the first ever call to succ(x) gets a function in return @call_counter decorator. 
However the main confusion here is I dont quite understand how sequential calls inside the for loop happens here?

So how does the flow go after we have a returned function (helper in this case) from first call.

Now inside the for loop, succ(0), succ(1) and so on gets called, how does that work? Do we reuse the same returned function that we got from the first call or does decorator gets called everytime the for loop gets added by 1?

Answer (score 1):

The decorator is applied only once when it is met and after that all invocations of `succ` use the same function you've returned `helper`.

This can be seen if you just printed the function object inside the `for` loop instead of calling it:

```
for i in range(10):
  print(succ)
<function call_counter.<locals>.helper at 0x7fe4d05139d8>
<function call_counter.<locals>.helper at 0x7fe4d05139d8>
# ... so on, ten times.
```

The flow is straight-forward, `helper` is called each and every time with the argument `x` which is passed to `func`.

Comment: Worth to mention that if you want to make your decorator transparent, you can use `functools.wraps`.

Comment: Thanks Jim but i think u meant to place the print(succ) inside of succ() and not inside of for loop right? but i get your point.